# Use string variable as field name in where condition in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a method  in the controller which checks if a field's value already exist in database.In my case I've to check for the multiple fields such as username, email, and URL via AJAX.

So I wrote the function below

```
  def check_field_already_exist?(field, params )

    merchant_url = MerchantUrl.where(field: filter_params[field.to_sym]).first

     # here params[:id] is available only while editing the MerchantUrl
     is_available = if (params[:id] && merchant_url)
                 merchant_url.id == params[:id]
               else
                 merchant_url.blank?
               end
  end
```

and invoke this method as

```
  def is_name_available
    render json: check_field_already_exist?('username', params)
  end

  def is_url_available
    render json: check_field_already_exist?('url', params)
  end

  def is_email_available
    render json: check_field_already_exist?('email', params)
  end
```

but on execution it throws the error

Mysql2::Error: **Unknown column 'merchant_urls.field'** in 'where clause': SELECT `merchant_urls`.* FROM `merchant_urls` WHERE `merchant_urls`.`field` = 'http://localhost:3000'

So, Is there any method to use string variable as field name?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The *proper* way is to use the good old hashrocket syntax

```
merchant_url = MerchantUrl.where(field => filter_params[field])
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you are doing this the wrong way round. As you are passing the id into the method (within params), why not use that to get the `merchant_url` and then check if the field has content:

```
def check_field_already_exist?(field, id=nil)
  if id && merchant_url = MerchantUrl.find(id)
    merchant_url.send(field).try('present?')
  else
    MerchantUrl.exists?(field => filter_params[field.to_sym])
  end 
end
```

You can then

```
def is_name_available
  render json: check_field_already_exist?('username', params[:id])
end
```

Though personally, I'd have a method that returned the model instance attributes hash as json, and then check through the contents of the hash with JavaScript client side. That way you can get the data you want with only one call back to the server (rather than one for each field).

Comment: Thank you ReggieB I don't have params[:id] in all cases.
I'm using same method in both new and edit case. So If I validate the new form it doesn't pass id but in case of edit form it does so.

Comment: @bipashant I've modified my answer, so that it will work if there is no id (in which case, it will return nil).

Comment: @bipashant I've modified my answer again, so that it will check for those fields in other merchant urls if there isn't an existing one.

Comment: Hi
Thanks a lot
but I got this error 

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)):
  app/controllers/merchant_urls_controller.rb:44:in `check_field_already_exist?'
  app/controllers/merchant_urls_controller.rb:16:in `is_name_available'

when params[:id] is nill

Comment: Did you notice I'd swapped the order of the parameters in `is_name_available` ?

Comment: I changed the order but it's actually on MerchantUrl.exists?(field, filter_params[field.to_sym])

Comment: @bipashant sorry my mistake. I've corrected the exists code.

Comment: Thank you @Reggie
you made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

In yor code `field` is a symbol that identifies column name.
You should do like this:

```
merchant_url = MerchantUrl.where("#{field} = ?", filter_params[field.to_sym])
```

Comment: Just remember here that #{field} can be used for SQL injection, so take care not to expose it as input on how to determine its value. I believe we can reach the same more safely with [Sergio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32370195/2985644)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

```
def check_field_already_exist?(field, params )

    merchant_url = MerchantUrl.where("#{field}=?", filter_params[field.to_sym]).first

    is_available = if (params[:id] && merchant_url)
                     merchant_url.id == params[:id]
                   else
                     merchant_url.nil?
                   end
  end
```

But make sure `field` should not be something that end-user can set via params.. Other wise it would be extremely vulnerable.

Comment: I've surprised that this works as `where` will return a collection of merchant_url instances. So the following `merchant_url.id` will either error or return the id of the collection. You could use `find_by` rather than `where`, but that would find the first and might miss the one you are after. You could try `mechant_url.collect(&:id).include?(params[:id])` or use my alternative.

Comment: I think it would be better if you edit your answer accordingly @ReggieB

Comment: My answer gets around this issue by only doing the `where` query if there is no existing merchant url. - so I don't think there is a need to edit it.

Comment: anyway your first comment above is really helpful, appreciate that